# Python Parse JSON value with space delimited subfields

Tags: python, json

I need to parse JSON like this:

```
{
    "entity": " a=123455 b=234234 c=S d=CO e=1 f=user1 timestamp=null",
    "otherField": "text"
}
```

I want to get values for a, b, c, d, e, timestamp separately.  Is there a better way than assigning the entity value to a string, then parsing with REGEX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
>>> dic = dict(item.split("=") for item in s['entity'].strip().split(" "))
>>> dic 
>>> {'a': '123455', 'c': 'S', 'b': '234234', 'e': '1', 'd': 'CO', 'f': 'user1', 'timestamp':'null'}
>>> dic['a']
'123455'
>>> dic['b']
'234234'
>>> dic['c']
'S'
>>> dic['d']
'CO'
>>>
```

Comment: Take into account that `str.split(' ')` leads to empty elements if there is more than one consecutive space. `str.split()` (or `str.split(None)` splits on *arbitrary width* whitespace, and removes the need for using `str.strip()` first.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to the JSON standard that parses that value for you, you'll have to do this in Python.

It could be easier to just split that string on whitespace, then on `=`:

```
entities = dict(keyvalue.split('=', 1) for keyvalue in data['entity'].split())
```

This results in:

```
>>> data = {'entity': " a=123455 b=234234 c=S d=CO e=1 f=user1 timestamp=null"}
>>> dict(keyvalue.split('=', 1) for keyvalue in data['entity'].split())
{'a': '123455', 'c': 'S', 'b': '234234', 'e': '1', 'd': 'CO', 'f': 'user1', 'timestamp': 'null'}
```